# Mac Catalina Xcode 12.0.1 IOS Build Error Urbanairship

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, macos-catalina, urbanairship.com

Facing build issue with Urbanairship package, recently updated to Catalina and xcode12.
Works fine with Xcode11 and Mojave. Any suggestions, please? I am using react native 0.61.1 version.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the Urbanairsip version fixed the issue for me.